# How to convert a string to datetime in python?

Tags: python

```
now = datetime.strptime(str(col[4].text), '%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M:%S')

print(type(now))
```

But the output says that the type of the `now` variable is: `class 'datetime.datetime'`

How to convert it to a custom format?

Comment: [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)'s docs clearly indicate a `datetime` will be returned. What did you expect?

Comment: What are you asking for? What you are trying to do worked and that's a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Datetime objects have a default format when they are printed. The format section of `strptime` defineds the string format that the datetime STARTS as. Once it is converted to a datetime, it uses the standard representation defined by `__repr__` and `__str__`.

To convert these values to strings in the format that you want, you can use `strftime`:

```
now = datetime.strptime(str(col[4].text), '%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M:%S')
now = now.strftime('%d.%m.%Y, %H:%M:%S')
```

The docs for datetime objects states that `print(datetime_object)` will return the ISO format representation of `datetime_object`. ISO format is the YYYY-MM-DD format that you are seeing when printing the datetime.

Read more here: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html